# Android Bluetooth HID implementation

Tags: android, bluetooth, hid

While my code has been running on my Android phone successfully,
I still dont understand something below..

When I look into sdp.c file, I found there are some values such as:

HIDParserVersion

```
//HIDParserVersion   0x0201 uint16          mandatory   4.3.2

static const uint16_t attr_parser_version = 0x0111;
```

I understand that **0x201** is its attribute id and **0x0111** is its attribute value.
However, I dont understand why it is necessarily to be **0x0111** as its attribute value.
One more example is that its subclass is **0xcc**.

Could someone tell me: Where is the definition of these values?

Thank you

Comment: Hi Sam I think you successfully implemented android HID communication.
so I would like to know the procedure.Could you please help me to do this

Comment: yes i actually did it. But as you can see the post was around 3 years ago and I believe Android has changed a lot ( ex: from bluez to bluedroid ). Does it support HID yet ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the list of attributes at section "Human Interface Device Profile" in 
https://www.bluetooth.org/Technical/AssignedNumbers/service_discovery.htm

See the details including the values in e.g. "HID_SPEC_V11.pdf" from https://www.bluetooth.org/docman/handlers/downloaddoc.ashx?doc_id=246761 (via https://www.bluetooth.org/Technical/Specifications/adopted.htm)